# Irvine32.inc won't run on Microsoft Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm, irvine32

We just started out our lesson in Assembly language. A sample project was given to us to inspect the code. In school, we use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and the sample project runs perfectly. However, when I tried it on my laptop running Visual Studio 2015, I get an error that says

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   A1000   cannot open file : Irvine32.inc ASM_Project C:\Irvine \Examples\Project_sample\main.asm 3
```

and

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB3721 The command "ml64.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"x64\Release\main.obj" /I "c:\Irvine" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Tamain.asm" exited with code 1. ASM_Project C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets 50
```

I'm on a 64-bit Windows 10. And what I did was to open the .`sln` file of the project.

Here's the code.

```
TITLE MASM Template                     (main.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
myMessage BYTE "Assembly language program example",0dh,0ah,0

.code
main PROC
    call Clrscr

    mov  edx,OFFSET myMessage
    call WriteString

    exit
main ENDP

END main
```

I just can't figure out why it returns a message on Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and runs on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

I just have no idea because I haven't really programmed in `Assembly` language in the past.

By the way we're using Irvine32 library.

If there's any other compiler for Irvine32, I'd appreciate if you can also provide other alternatives.

Thank you.

Comment: _"C:\Irvine \Examples\Project_sample\main.asm"_ Is there supposed to be a space after "Irvine"?

Comment: @Michael You're actually correct Michael. I renamed the folder correctly and then run the code and it worked! Thanks. You solved it. I didn't know that it's that sensitive to spaces.

Comment: Paths containing spaces generally have to be enclosed in double quotes (e.g. `"C:\My Documents"`). Try opening a `cmd` window, type `c:\pro`, press the Tab key and see what happens.